# Best Practice to Save GPS Coordinates

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I'm developing my first android app and one of the features is tracking the user's route. At another point in the app I'm going to have a review and bring up another map to plot the locations. I implemented the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and set the minDistance to 50 meter and everything is working correctly. In the [onLocationChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)) I add the new location to a list. I'm wondering what, in your opinion, is the best way to save this list? Currently I'm just writing the list to the local SQLite db, but I'm wondering if this best or if there are other alternatives I should explore.

Thanks

Comment: If you're concerned about space and/or want something easily serializable, you might want to look at encoded polylines https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1

Comment: You are writing the new location to a list. And if you have a big list you write the list to a db. You could also write every new location directly to the db. For what you need that list further?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, just wasn't sure if there was a better approach. I was concerned about the size or number of rows in the db.